# Yodlee webhooks not hitting my URL

Tags: yodlee

I have been reading Yodlee Docs at https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Webhooks for implementing webhooks

What i did is, first registered a webhook for one of my users using following end point
`POST` `/{cobrandName}/v1/cobrand/config/notifications/events/{eventName}`

Then i triggered a refresh for one of the account using following endpoint 
 `POST` `/{cobrandName}/v1/refresh`

But seems that Yodlee doesnt hit my URL when refresh is completed or there is an error in refresh.

I also tried to add an account using FastLink to see if Yodlee hits my URL when an account is added. But it doesn't. I am not sure what exactly is the problem. Can you please help?

Although i have a dobt - Does the webhook hit only if add/edit/refresh account was done using the API and not FastLInk provided by yodlee?

I am using Account Agreegation API and Developer account for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Webhook event notifications will work only when you try to add the account using YSL APIs (manually).It doesn't work with FastLink. I have been informed by Yodlee Support. They also informed me that till date they don't have any client using webhook service, which was bit scary to know.

Answer (score 0):

Please find a simple example to use webhooks-

1)Subscribe event using this URL- http://webhook.info/post/FLQLMZMFJI

2)Initiate add account process

3)Open the following URL and find the refresh notifications -
http://webhook.info/#/watch/FLQLMZMFJI

Please note: As you have subscribed for webhook event now. Please unsubscribe first using

**DELETE /{cobrandName}/v1/cobrand/config/notifications/events/{eventName} 
Delete Subscription**